# Import XML exported from JIRA to other open source bugtracker

Tags: jira, bug-tracking

I want to import `XML` which is exported from `JIRA` to any open source bug tracker on daily basis. I have googled it but I was not able to find anything which points me to right direction.

Can you please help me if you know any open source bug tracker which can import bugs exported from JIRA?

Comment: which open source bug tracker are you looking at? Or any bug tracker tool would do?

Comment: @Anshu any open source bug tracker tool would do as it is temporary solution.

Answer (score 4):

Seems there is a script to import JIRA into [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/): http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/JiraToTracIntegration

A Blog post on going from JIRA to [Bugzilla](http://www.bugzilla.org/): http://www.bdunagan.com/2011/11/07/migrating-jira-to-bugzilla/

Comment: Thanks. I will look in to these and see if it works for me. If it works then I will accept it as answer

Comment: Tried this but runs in to lot of problems. And have to spent time on those. :( And still it does not work with import from xml for bugzilla.